# Compile error during compilation with javac

Tags: grails

I have a grails project I'm trying to compile. 
Compilation always ends up with an error after compiling the source files of the project. I have a "Compile error during compilation with javac" stacktrace which returns me 11 errors about 11 classes.

Her is one of the 11 errors:

```
d:\Profiles\jMichel\AppData\Local\Temp\groovy-generated-937113616033442252-java-source\fr\myProject\blockA\FicheClassA.java:683: error: getConstraints() in FicheClassA cannot override getConstraints() in AbstractBaseEntity
public static  java.lang.Object getConstraints() { return null;}
                                ^
return type Object is not compatible with Map
```

FYI all these 11 classes are related to each others (belongsTo or hasMany or else kind of link) and are heritated from AbstractBaseEntity class.

Here is the AbstractBaseEntity :

```
    @Validateable
abstract class AbstractBaseEntity {
transient springSecurityService

Date dateCreation
String loginCreation
Date dateMaj
String loginMaj
Boolean archive = false

static mapping = {
    tablePerHierarchy false
    dateCreation column: 'DATE_CREATION'
    loginCreation column: 'LOGIN_CREATION'
    dateMaj column: 'DATE_MAJ'
    loginMaj column: 'LOGIN_MAJ'
    archive column: 'ARCHIVE'
}

static constraints = {
    dateCreation nullable: true
    loginCreation nullable: true
    dateMaj nullable: true
    loginMaj nullable: true
    archive nullable: true
}

def beforeInsert = {
    dateCreation = new Date()
    loginCreation = springSecurityService?.principal instanceof String ? springSecurityService.principal : springSecurityService?.principal?.username
}

def beforeUpdate = {
    dateMaj = new Date()
    loginMaj = springSecurityService?.principal instanceof String ? springSecurityService.principal : springSecurityService?.principal?.username
}

}
```

Comment: it seems as you declared an overriden method `getConstraints()` in  `FicheClassA` that isn´t valid to override the method `getConstraints()` from your `AbstractBaseEntity`

Comment: In fact I don't use any getConstraints explicitely in FicheClassA...Nothing in my FicheClassA seems wrong... Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your Groovy class `AbstractBaseEntity` defines a static Closure property named *constraints*. It's defined as follows:

```
static constraints = {
    dateCreation nullable: true
    loginCreation nullable: true
    dateMaj nullable: true
    loginMaj nullable: true
    archive nullable: true
}
```

When the Groovy class is compiled the Groovy compiler adds the getter/setter methods for the *constraints* property.

1. static Object getConstraints()
2. static void setConstraints(Object)

The Java class `FicheClassA` inherits from the Groovy class `AbstractBaseEntity` and adds the method `static java.lang.Object getConstraints()`. Since Groovy nor Java allow two methods with the same name and arguments to exist in the same class (different return type doesn't count), the result is a compiler error.

I don't know why the Java compiler insists the return type of `AbstractBaseEntity.getConstraints()` is a `Map`. It should be `Object`. You can try changing it to a `Map` in `FicheClassA`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the origin of the problem, nevertheless I don't how to explain it...

For the record, an unused import (no reference was made in the class and compilator indicated me it was unused) of FicheClassA was made in an another class.

When I removed this import, compilation of the project worked fine...

Now the question is why?